# How to restore/forceDelete multiple item at once time in Laravel using soft delete

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

When I use restore method of soft delete it work`s well. But I want to do that multiple item restore at once time. Is it possible by soft delete? Any suggestion please. Thank you.

```
$products = Product::onlyTrashed()
            ->whereIn('id', $request->product_ids)
            ->get();

$products->restore();
```

Show the below error message.

`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::restore does not exist.`

Comment: Have you tried the following: `Product::onlyTrashed()->where('id', $request->product_id)->restore();`

Comment: Yea, It`s work. Tnx sir.

Comment: What about `Product::onlyTrashed()->whereIn('id', $array)->restore();` where `$array` is an array of the products IDs you want to restore.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: Yea, Your are right sir and you are owsome.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy.

Just use restore() method on eloquent instead of collection:

```
$products = Product::onlyTrashed()
    ->whereIn('id', $request->product_id)
    ->restore();
```